# Drupal 7 - Display different button conditionally

Tags: button, drupal, webforms

I am not really a drupal dev but I was asked to fix a webform on website.

At the moment each event has price but some events are free. There is special event category (Type of Event) called Free Workshop. 
Is it possible to change behaviour of submit button based on this category? At the moment users are redirected to Paypal where they have to pay 10eur deposit... but event is free so there should be no redirection and form should be just submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement hook form alter function and alter form depending on price or what ever you need it do depend on.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x

That's what you can do from back-end side. But if you want to alter it without page refresh (i.e. user changes some field, but page doesn't get refreshed by that action) then you'll have to go with JavaScript form altering.